# How do I align a number like this in C?

Tags: c, printf, alignment

I need to align a series of numbers in C with **printf()** like this example:

```
-------1
-------5
------50
-----100
----1000
```

Of course, there are numbers between all those but it's not relevant for the issue at hand... Oh, consider the dashes as spaces, I used dashes so it was easier to understand what I want.

I'm only able to do this:

```
----1---
----5---
----50--
----100-
----1000
```

Or this:

```
---1
---5
--50
-100
1000
```

But none of this is what I want and I can't achieve what is displayed on the first example using only printf(). Is it possible at all?

**EDIT:**
Sorry people, I was in a hurry and didn't explain myself well... My last example and all your suggestions (to use something like "%8d") do not work because, although the last number is 1000 it doesn't necessarily go all the way to 1000 or even 100 or 10 for that matter.

No matter the number of digits to be displayed, I only want 4 leading spaces at most for the largest number. Let's say I have to display digits from 1 to 1000 (A) and 1 to 100 (B) and I use, for both, "%4d", this would be the output:

**A:**

```
---1
....
1000
```

Which is the output I want...

**B:**

```
---1
....
-100
```

Which is not the output I want, I actually want this:

```
--1
...
100
```

But like I said, I don't know the exact number of numbers I have to print, it can have 1 digit, it can have 2, 3 or more, the function should be prepared for all. And I want four extra additional leading spaces but that's not that relevant.

**EDIT 2:**
It seems that what I want, the way I need it, it's not possible (check David Thornley and Blank Xavier answers and my comments). Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Im not sure about C, but C++ you can output to a file and play with width precision, so if this can also be done in C someone let me know then I'll try to help out with an answer

Comment: Isn't this just a right-adjustment issue?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Looking this up in my handy Harbison & Steele....

Determine the maximum width of fields.

```
int max_width, value_to_print;
max_width = 8;
value_to_print = 1000;
printf("%*d\n", max_width, value_to_print);
```

Bear in mind that max_width must be of type `int` to work with the asterisk, and you'll have to calculate it based on how much space you're going to want to have.  In your case, you'll have to calculate the maximum width of the largest number, and add 4.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the largest number, I'll never know until I reach it. And I need to do this on the fly...

Comment: @Nazgulled: So in other words, you're asking a question that's impossible by definition?

Comment: I guess... But I didn't know it was impossible until some of your answers.

Comment: Isn't this just a right-adjustment question? At least that's what I understand it to be.

Comment: Say you're reading in a file and displaying line numbers... you would be able to know the largest number.

Read all the way until the end counting \n and then care about the content. Programs that have no restrictions from a memory point of view can just load up 2GB files directly into memory, so that way it's only one set of file operations.

Answer (score 56):

Why is `printf("%8d\n", intval);` not working for you? It should...

You did not show the format strings for any of your "not working" examples, so I'm not sure what else to tell you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i <= 10000; i*=10) {
                printf("[%8d]\n", i);
        }
        return (0);
}

$ ./printftest
[       1]
[      10]
[     100]
[    1000]
[   10000]
```

**EDIT:** response to clarification of question:

```
#include <math.h>
int maxval = 1000;
int width = round(1+log(maxval)/log(10));
...
printf("%*d\n", width, intval);
```

The width calculation computes log base 10 + 1, which gives the number of digits. The fancy `*` allows you to use the variable for a value in the format string.

You still have to know the maximum for any given run, but there's no way around that in any language or pencil & paper.

Comment: Had no idea about the variable sized width, cool!

Answer (score 4):

```
    printf("%8d\n",1);
    printf("%8d\n",10);
    printf("%8d\n",100);
    printf("%8d\n",1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

*[I realize this question is a million years old, but there is a deeper question (or two) at its heart, about OP, the pedagogy of programming, and about assumption-making.]*

A few people, including a mod, have suggested this is impossible.  And, in some--including the most obvious--contexts, it is.  But it's interesting to see that that wasn't immediately obvious to the OP.

The impossibility assumes that the contex is running an executable compiled from C on a line-oriented text console (e.g., console+sh or X-term+csh or Terminal+bash), which is a very reasonable assumption.  But the fact that the "right" answer ("`%8d`") wasn't good enough for OP while also being non-obvious suggests that there's a pretty big can of worms nearby...

Consider Curses (and its many variants).  In it, you *can* navigate the "screen", and "move" the cursor around, and "repaint" portions (windows) of text-based output.  In a Curses context, it absolutely *would be* possible to do; i.e., dynamically resize a "window" to accommodate a larger number.  But even Curses is just a screen "painting" abstraction.  No one suggested it, and probably rightfully so, because a Curses implementation **in C** doesn't mean it's "strictly C".  Fine.

But what does this really mean?  In order for the response: "it's impossible" to be correct, it would mean that we're saying something about the runtime system.  In other words, this isn't theoretical, (as in, "How do I sort a statically-allocated array of `int`s?"), which can be explained as a "closed system" that totally ignores any aspect of the runtime.

But, in this case, we have I/O: specifically, the implementation of `printf()`.  But that's where there's an opportunity to have said something more interesting in response (even though, admittedly, the asker was probably not digging quite this deep).

Suppose we use a different set of assumptions.  Suppose OP is reasonably "clever" and understands that it would not be possible to to edit previous lines on a line-oriented stream (how would you correct the horizontal position of a character output by a line-printer??).  Suppose also, that OP isn't just a kid working on a homework assignment and not realizing it was a "trick" question, intended to tease out an exploration of the meaning of "stream abstraction".  Further, let's suppose OP was wondering: "Wait...If C's runtime environment supports the idea of STDOUT--and if STDOUT is just an abstraction--why isn't it just as reasonable to have a terminal abstraction that 1) can vertically scroll but 2) supports a positionable cursor?  Both are moving text on a screen."

Because if *that* were the question we're trying to answer, then you'd only have to look as far as:

[ANSI Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

to see that:

> Almost all manufacturers of video terminals added vendor-specific escape sequences to perform operations such as placing the cursor at arbitrary positions on the screen. One example is the VT52 terminal, which allowed the cursor to be placed at an x,y location on the screen by sending the ESC character, a Y character, and then two characters representing with numerical values equal to the x,y location plus 32 (thus starting at the ASCII space character and avoiding the control characters). The Hazeltine 1500 had a similar feature, invoked using ~, DC1 and then the X and Y positions separated with a comma. While the two terminals had identical functionality in this regard, different control sequences had to be used to invoke them.
>
> The first popular video terminal to support these sequences was the Digital VT100, introduced in 1978. This model was very successful in the market, which sparked a variety of VT100 clones, among the earliest and most popular of which was the much more affordable Zenith Z-19 in 1979. Others included the Qume QVT-108, Televideo TVI-970, Wyse WY-99GT as well as optional "VT100" or "VT103" or "ANSI" modes with varying degrees of compatibility on many other brands. The popularity of these gradually led to more and more software (especially bulletin board systems and other online services) assuming the escape sequences worked, leading to almost all new terminals and emulator programs supporting them.

It *has* been possible, as early as 1978.  C itself was "born" in 1972, and the K&R version was established in 1978.  If "ANSI" escape sequences were around at that time, then there is an answer "in C" if we're willing to also stipulate: "Well, assuming your terminal is VT100-capable."  Incidentally, the consoles which don't support ANSI escapes?  You guessed it: Windows & DOS consoles.  But on almost every other platform (Unices, Vaxen, Mac OS, Linux) you can expect to.

TL;DR - There is no reasonable answer that can be given without stating assumptions about the runtime environment.  Since most runtimes (unless you're using desktop-computer-market-share-of-the-80's-and-90's to calculate 'most') would have, (since the time of the VT-52!), then I don't think it's entirely justified to say that it's impossible--just that in order for it to be possible, it's an entire different order of magnitude of work, and not as simple as `%8d`...which it kinda seemed like the OP knew about.

**We just have to clarify the assumptions.**

And lest one thinks that I/O is exceptional, i.e., the only time we need to think about the runtime, (or even the hardware), just dig into IEEE 754 Floating Point exception handling.  For those interested:

[Intel Floating Point Case Study](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/case-studies/floating-point-case-study.pdf)

> According to Professor William Kahan, University of California at
>   Berkeley, a classic case occurred in June 1996. A satellite-lifting
>   rocket named Ariane 5 turned cartwheels shortly after launch and
>   scattered itself and a payload worth over half a billion dollars over
>   a marsh in French Guiana. Kahan found the disaster could be blamed
>   upon a programming language that disregarded the default
>   exception-handling specifications in IEEE 754. Upon launch, sensors
>   reported acceleration so strong that it caused a conversion-to-integer
>   overflow in software intended for recalibration of the rocket’s
>   inertial guidance while on the launching pad.

Comment: Although you didnt get to the point of directly answering the question with your findings - I love this :)
One problem remains - pulling too much env into the consideration can cause arbitrary hard or complex circumstances. Imho thats part of the ongoing learning during life - to learn where to cut things to keep them handy...

Answer (score 2):

So, you want an 8-character wide field with spaces as the padding? Try "%8d". [Here's a reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).

**EDIT**: What you're trying to do is not something that can be handled by printf alone, because it will not know what the longest number you are writing is. You will need to calculate the largest number before doing any printfs, and then figure out how many digits to use as the width of your field. Then you can use snprintf or similar to make a printf format on the spot.

```
char format[20];
snprintf(format, 19, "%%%dd\\n", max_length);
while (got_output) {
    printf(format, number);
    got_output = still_got_output();
}
```

Comment: printf("%*d", width, value) is less work than constructing the format string, probably less error-prone, and probably clearer. It might conceivably be slower because of the additional argument to printf() (think lots of variable fields), so the technique you illustrate does have value in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting to a string and then use "%4.4s" as the format specifier. This makes it a fixed width format.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the question, the amount of padding you want will vary according to the data you have.  Accordingly, the only solution to this is to scan the data before printing, to figure out the widest datum, and so find a width value you can pass to printf using the asterix operator, e.g.

```
loop over data - get correct padding, put into width

printf( "%*d\n", width, datum );
```

Comment: Then you can't do it.  If you need to print a datum, and what you print depends on following data, and you don't know what those data will be, then you are attempting an impossible task.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't know the width in advance, then your only possible answer would depend on staging your output in a temporary buffer of some kind. For small reports, just collecting the data and deferring output until the input is bounded would be simplest.

For large reports, an intermediate file may be required if the collected data exceeds reasonable memory bounds.

Once you have the data, then it is simple to post-process it into a report using the idiom `printf("%*d", width, value)` for each value.

Alternatively if the output channel permits random access, you could just go ahead and write a draft of the report that assumes a (short) default width, and seek back and edit it any time your width assumption is violated. This also assumes that you can pad the report lines outside that field in some innocuous way, or that you are willing to replace the output so far by a read-modify-write process and abandon the draft file.

But unless you can predict the correct width in advance, it will not be possible to do what you want without some form of two-pass algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the edited question, you need to find the number of digits in the largest number to be presented, and then generate the `printf()` format using `sprintf()`, or using `%*d` with the number of digits being passed as an int for the `*` and then the value.  Once you've got the biggest number (and you have to determine that in advance), you can determine the number of digits with an 'integer logarithm' algorithm (how many times can you divide by 10 before you get to zero), or by using `snprintf()` with the buffer length of zero, the format `%d` and null for the string; the return value tells you how many characters would have been formatted.

If you don't know and cannot determine the maximum number ahead of its appearance, you are snookered - there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int i,j,n,b;
 printf("Enter no of rows ");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 b=n;
 for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
 {
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        printf("%*d",b,j);
        b=1;
    }
        b=n;
    b=b-i;
    printf("\n");


 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fp = fopen("RKdata.dat","w");
fprintf(fp,"%5s %12s %20s %14s %15s %15s %15s\n","j","x","integrated","bessj2","bessj3","bessj4","bessj5");
for (j=1;j<=NSTEP;j+=1)
    fprintf(fp,"%5i\t %12.4f\t %14.6f\t %14.6f\t %14.6f\t %14.6f\t %14.6f\n",
    j,xx[j],y[6][j],bessj(2,xx[j]),bessj(3,xx[j]),bessj(4,xx[j]),bessj(5,xx[j]));
fclose(fp);
```