# How can I align with tab key? There is some problem

Tags: c

In visual studio, C programming
If I align with tab key(\t), I have some problem.

for example, If I print example below

```
aaa\t123\t1234\n
bbb\t456\t4567\n
abcd\t456\t4567\n
```

I get kind of

```
aaa    123    1234
bbb    456    4567
abcd          456    4567
```

Can I solve this problem? I want to make third line align with first and second line.
Even if I insert 2 tab key (\t\t), problem is not solved.

Comment: See the `printf` function, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420924/aligning-output-values-in-c)

Comment: Consider formatting with spaces instead. A tab stop is open to interpretation but a space is always a space.